# narrowing conversion on struct initialization

Tags: c++

```
struct st {
    unsigned short a;
    unsigned short b;
};

int main(){
    unsigned short a(10), b(10);

    st{ a + b, a - b };

    return 0;
}
```

Issues an error on the line of initialization list:

> error C2397: conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned short' requires a
>   narrowing conversion

So I believe implicit conversion to 'int' has taken place. I didn't ask for it. What do I do to prevent it from happening?

```
int main(){
  unsigned short a(10), b(10), c;

  c = a + b;

  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles well though

Comment: Unfortunately you've stumbled into the trap that there is nothing smaller than an `int` that the arithmetic operators work with.  If size isn't a constraint I'd suggest using a `unsigned int` or larger type for your members.

Comment: maybe consider to add a constructor along the line of `st(unsigned short x,unsigned short y) : a(x+y),b(x-y) {}`

Comment: @user463035818 I guess the posted code is only to show an example of the more general case of a constructor called with a temporary (which the OP could define, by the way).

Answer (score 5):

Indeed `a + b` is an `int` type, since an `unsigned short` is a narrower type.

Notwithstanding the potential for (defined) overflow, to circumvent this you'll need to provide a cast:

```
st{ (unsigned short)(a + b), (unsigned short)(a - b) };
```

or use a `static_cast` if you want to be very explicit. If you don't like repeating your types (I'm of this ilk), you could write

```
st{ static_cast<decltype(st.a)>(a + b), static_cast<decltype(st.b)>(a - b) }
```

Adding a constructor to your class is another option.

Comment: What's next? Adding two floats will implicitly convert to double? Seriously, what the heck, man...

Comment: @user3600124: All arithmetic operations are performed at an `int`, as a minimum. It's life I'm afraid.

Comment: @user3600124 No, but adding int (of any size) to a float will promote the integer to a float.

Comment: There are several constructor options :/ (`st(int, int)`, `st(unsigned short, unsigned short)`). One allows to hide any narrowing with *misleading* interface. the other doesn't really resolve the issue as there is still diagnostic for `st{ a + b, a - b }` but allow to be called with `st(a + b, a - b )`...